# How do I set a specific image for a Spotify Playlist

Tags: image, playlist, spotify

Is it possible to set a specific image that will appear when people share my Spotify playlist instead of the default collage of album covers?  I've seen companies do this.

Example of what I want:
http://open.spotify.com/user/herbalessencesus/playlist/2oJKDuEbhByNCZHMqmDenR

Example of what I'm getting:
http://open.spotify.com/user/124792730/playlist/0Y2wUYw5wxMdZGCqJyqbaA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first link you shared is a special, branded playlist.

If you're acting on behalf of a company, and you want to get in touch with us about that, please fill out the partner contact form: http://www.spotify.com/us/work-with-us/partners/contact/

Comment: I am working on behalf of a company that want's a branded playlist.  I've looked at the form.  Is there anything they need to specifically ask for?

Comment: Explain why you want to make a branded playlist. If you don't hear back, email me: mager [at] spotify.com

Comment: Hi @mager, given your reply is from 2012 I assume you no longer work at Spotify. If you by the off chance still do would you be able to reply to the epic feature request which has 6000+ votes and 54 pages of comments literally begging for this functionality for at least premium users. Spotify's silence on this seems astounding. https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Customization-of-playlists-cover-and-description-box/idi-p/211048/page/54#comments

Answer (score 2):

You can do it also in the App itself by overriding the CSS and put a background image.
Not sure, that's what you want.